# Swagger codegen cannot find ignore file

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

I am trying to run the swagger codegen tool and get the error,

`No .swagger-codegen-ignore file found.`

I have created this file in the same directory from which I am running a command like,

`java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.1.jar generate -l kotlin -i ./src/main/resources/backend_openapi.json -o ./src/main/resources/client`

I have double checked the spelling of the ignore file but not sure why it cannot recognize it? Does it need to be in a different location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Swagger Codegen docs](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#ignore-file-format) (emphasis mine):

> The .swagger-codegen-ignore file must exist in the **root of the output directory**.

In your example, it needs to be in the `src/main/resources/client` folder.

If the ignore file is in another location, use the `--ignore-file-override=/path/to/ignore_file` CLI option.